# Do I sacrifice benefits if leave the country when on maternity/paternity leave?

Tags: germany, benefits, india

My wife (Polish citizen) and I (German citizen) are in family planning now. We are both employed in Germany.

We would like to spend a year or two living and working in India, and we thought that it would be practical to combine that with me or my wife taking paternity/maternity leave from our job in Germany. Thus we could have some stable base-income when going to India, and we would have at least one job waiting for us when we came back. Is this idea workable or would some laws restrict this plan?

Any experience with going abroad while on parental leave is appreciated :)

Comment: Are you going to take your new born child to India? If you do not return on time before matertniy/paternity ends the company might sue you for costs. Otherwise its not the government's problem but your companies. So if they are nice tell them, if not, don't tell them and make sure to get back in time. A year or two? That is a long time? Isn't it usualy a several months form company? I suppose you get basic paternity form goverment.

Comment: @ppumkin That's definitely not true as a general rule, there are countries where such things are regulated by law.

Comment: Yea... but they have to find out first and the most popular way is when somebody grasses you up. I do neither of these things but when people are desperate for some cash, they take bigger chances.

Answer (score 3):

In Germany your wife will receive maternity benefit (Mutterschaftsgeld) for only 14 weeks - 6 weeks before the birth and 8 weeks after the birth.

After that you can receive parents money (Elternsgeld) for up to 14 months after the birth but only if you're residents of Germany.

I have no first-hand experince but I think it's not possible to go to India for a year and still getting parents money or maternity benefits in Germany.

For more information:

- [BEEG](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/beeg/BJNR274810006.html)
- [MuSchG (Maternity Protection Act)](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/muschg/BJNR000690952.html)